# In Python, how do I return a value from a function when an `if` statement is executed?

Tags: python, recursion, return

In this function, I want to return a value when the `if` statement is executed.

Since Python always returns something, it returns `None`.

```
def Persistence(number, counter):
    numArr = [int(i) for i in str(number)]
    result = 1
    data = None
    for j in numArr:
        result *= j
    if len(str(number)) == 1:
        data = str(f'Done. {counter} steps taken')
        print(data)
        # return data
    else:
        counter = counter + 1
        Persistence(result, counter)
    # return data

print(Persistence(333,0))
```

Maybe I put the `return` keyword in the wrong place (I checked by putting it in two different places, marked as a comment) or something else, but I couldn't figure it out.

Please help me out. Also, if there is another way to count the recursion steps besides my technique, please let me know.

Comment: You can return something inside an `if` and/or `else` block inside a defined function.

Comment: I tried that, it returns `none`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this :

```
def Persistence(number, counter):
    numArr = [int(i) for i in str(number)]
    result = 1

    for j in numArr:
        result *= j
    if len(str(number)) == 1:
        return str(f'Done. {counter} steps taken')

    counter = counter + 1
    return Persistence(result, counter)

print(Persistence(333,0))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But the problem is, you and @Mason Caiby both gave the right answer. I'm confused which ones should I accept as an answer. :P

Comment: Ahah, I don't mind as long as it solved your problem :p

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're not setting the value from the `else` call to `persistence` to anything. The following code return the data value for me:

```
def Persistence(number, counter):
    numArr = [int(i) for i in str(number)]
    result = 1
    data = None
    for j in numArr:
        result *= j
    if len(str(number)) == 1:
        data = str(f'Done. {counter} steps taken')
        print(data)
        return data
    else:
        counter = counter + 1
        data = Persistence(result, counter)
    return data

x = Persistence(333, 0)
```

Then if we print x:

```
print(x)
# Done. 3 steps taken
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But the problem is, you and @Flo both gave the right answer. I'm confused which ones should I accept as an answer. :P

Comment: @MahmudulHasan haha I dont care, I think Flo's answer is a little cleaner, I was just trying to show why it wouldn't return what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic to count the recursion steps is basically correct, you just need to place the `return` statements for both the: 
1)Base case 
2)The recursive call itself

The following modification to your code will do the trick of what you are asking:

```
def Persistence(number, counter):
    numArr = [int(i) for i in str(number)]
    result = 1
    data = None
    for j in numArr:
        result *= j
    if len(str(number)) == 1:
        data = str(counter)
        return data
    else:
        counter = counter + 1
        return Persistence(result, counter)


print(Persistence(333,0))
```

The above code will return the output of:

```
3
```

Please note that the reason you were getting "None" as the output in your original code is because you were not making a return at the actual recursive call itself: `**return** Persistence(result, counter)`

So when you ran `print(Persistence(333,0))` it was returning nothing resulting in the `None`.

Answer (score 1):

This question is better to learn about recursion than you may think. But we won't muddy the waters by mixing recursion (functional style) with statements and side effects (imperative style).

It looks like you're trying to calculate multiplicative root and persistence. Instead of putting all concerns of the computation into a single function, break it down into sensible parts -

```
def digits (n = 0):
  if n < 10:
    return [ n ]
  else:
    return digits (n // 10) + [ n % 10 ]

def product (n = 0, *more):
  if not more:
    return n
  else:
    return n * product (*more)

def mult_root (n = 0):
  if n < 10:
    return [ n ]
  else:
    return [ n ] + mult_root (product (*digits (n)))

def mult_persistence (n = 0):
  return len (mult_root (n)) - 1

print (mult_persistence (333))
# 3

print (mult_root (333))
# [ 333, 27, 14, 4 ]
```